# Why isn't the mass of the things dissolved in water not added to the mass of the water in an enthalpy calc?

Tags: thermodynamics, enthalpy

Take a change in enthalpy question. When $\pu{5 g}$ of powder is dissolved in $\ce{100 ml}$ of water, the added substance raises the temperature of the water by $\ce{5 ^\circ C}$ and you are told to find the enthalpy change of the system. Since $Q=mc\Delta T, c=4.19, \Delta T=5$, but why does the mass equal $\pu{100 g}$ rather than the combined mass of water and the dissolve powder which is $\ce{105 g}$?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Chemistry SE! Going forward, please use [$\LaTeX$](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) to format your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's get specific here. The "system" consists of $\pu{100 g}$ of water ($c_w = \pu{4.18 J/gK}$) and $\pu{5 g}$ of powder ($c_p$). If the initial temperature of the powder is $T_p$, final temperature is $T_p'$ and that of the water is $T_w$, then the enthalpy change of the system would be:
$$\Delta H = H_f - H_i \\
= m_wc_w(T_w+5-T_w) + m_pc_p(T_p'-T_p)$$

Due to the system being in equilibrium, the final temperature of the powder $T_p' = T_w + 5$:

$$\Delta H = m_wc_w\times 5 + m_pc_p\times(T_w+5-T_p)$$
As you can see, the enthalpy change obviously depends on the value of $T_w$, $T_p$ and $m_p$. Let's make some realistic assumptions: the "powder" is $\ce{NaCl}$ ($c_p = \pu{0.85 J/gK}$) and $T_p = T_w + 10$ (reasonable to assume, if the water is at $\pu{15 ^\circ C}$ and salt at $\pu{25 ^\circ C}$). Substituting values, we see that
$$\Delta H = 2090 - 21.25 = 2068.75$$
As a percentage, the change in enthalpy of the powder is
$$\frac{\Delta H_{\text{powder}}}{\Delta H} \times 100 = \frac{21.25}{2068.75} \times 100 \approx 1\%$$

therefore, **You don't count the enthalpy change of the powder because it's negligible**. If you had to account for change in enthalpy of powder as well, you would have been given the specific heat constant and temperature of the powder in the problem.

---

Note that if we make unrealistic assumptions, the enthalpy of powder would become significant. If you drop $\pu{5 g}$ sodium chloride at a temperature of $\pu{1000 K}$ into $\pu{100 g}$ water at $\pu{298 K}$, then almost all of your water would evaporate and you would have a very different calculation on your hands (one that involves pressure as well).

Comment: Who says you can linearly superimpose the enthalpies of the pure substances to get the enthalpy of a non-ideal solution?  That is not  valid.  It is only valid for an ideal solution.